# ChartsAmchartsBookingStatisticsLYC is not a function

Tags: javascript

Uncaught TypeError: ChartsAmchartsBookingStatisticsLYC is not a function.

anyone please resolve the issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post the relevant code causing this problem.

Comment: can you provide relevant code , thanks .

Comment: You should explain with more detail. Could you please share your code?